# Attached a file from drive to an email

Tags: python, node.js, email, google-drive-api, pydrive

I want to send file to a list of email, but i don't know how to attached a fill from drive, i know the id of my pdf but it doesn't work.

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders
from pathlib import Path

sender_email = "mail"
receiver_email = "mail"
password = "passeword"

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "multipart test"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  # we are dealing with dictionary, so you can use get method
  report = row.get('report')
  date2 = row.get('date2')
  to_email = row.get('mail')
  cc1 = row.get('cc1')
  cc2 = row.get('cc2')
  text = row.get('text')
  filename = date2+report
  file_list = drive.ListFile({
      'q':f"title contains '${filename}'  and mimeType='application/pdf' and trashed=false",
      'supportsAllDrives':True,
      'corpora': "teamDrive",
      'teamDriveId': 'ID',
      'supportsTeamDrives' :True,
      'includeItemsFromAllDrives':True,
  }).GetList()

  html = """\
  <html>
   <body>
     <p>Hi,<br>
        How are you?<br>
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  """


  # create MIMEText objects
  part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
  
  # attach the text/html part to the MIMEmultipart message
  message.attach(part1)

  # attaching an attachement 

  with open('https://drive.google.com/open?id=IDexample', "rb") as f:
      attach = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(f.read(),_subtype="pdf")
      attach = MIMEApplication(f.read(),_subtype="pdf")
  attach.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=str(path_to_pdf))
  msg.attach(attach)

  # create a secure SSL context
  context = ssl.create_default_context()
  
  # log in and send the email
  with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, to_email, message.as_string())
```

Everythings work except the attachment, so i add a list of email in my spreetsheet, and several information. I search my file with my information in my spreadsheet

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - what happens instead?

Comment: it doesn't find the file maybe it's because it's from drive

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the email get sent just without the attachment? Please help me to help you

Comment: I have the following error : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=IDexemple' of course it's a real ID, it doesn't send the email

Comment: You need to use the Drive API to get the file and attach it. [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) is the method you need. Check out the quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)